# Is there any way to retrieve kubeconfig for GKE using golang sdk

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, automation, sdk

I am trying to retrieve the kubeconfig file for GKE using Golang SDK.But after many attempts of searching it in various ways, I was unable to find a way.I need a way to retrieve all the kubeconfig files present in GCP account and need to know if there is any client for GCP just as godo(for DigitalOcean).

Comment: Not sure of what you want to do: Do you want to read the kubeconfig file stored on the server and to decode/understand it in your GO code?

Comment: Yes.I want to query the GCP account to retrieve  all kubeconfig files and kubeclusters using golang sdk.

Comment: Not clearer.... "Query the GCP account to retrieve all kubeconfig". There isn't kubeconfig in GCP account. You have access to GCP projects, and some can have GKE clusters